# when subtracting two vectors, does it matter which one you subtract from what?

Tags: vector-spaces

If I have two vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{CD}$, is saying $\vec{CD} - \vec{AD}$ the same as $\vec{AD} - \vec{CD}$? If not, what will be the difference in the two resulting vectors? Direction only, or... ?

Comment: Two real numbers: $a-b=-(b-a)$ can be regarded as an identity in a $1$-dimensional real vector space. Sometimes the simplest models are best for testing how ideas might work.

Answer (score 1):

Only the direction will differ. You will get the negative of the other. Thus the length is the same, only it is flipped in the opposite direction. This holds for all dimensions